# Regular Expression text insertion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some string that could be on a URL.. ala.. I can "get the name/value" etc.. that is not the issue. The issue is that given some test I need to "insert" additional characters in the value. so:

```
var someValue = "yes_maybe_next_year"
```

If I get a string with "_maybe" in it, I would insert my additional chars after it, ala.
so it would become:

```
var charsToInsert = "_no";
var someValue = "yes_maybe_next_year";
var newValue = "yes_maybe_no_next_year";
```

Here is the rub. I might not get "maybe" in there. So I need to insert "_no" after "yes".
Here is a second rub. The string might contain chars that are different than "next_year".

```
var someValue = "yes_sometime_later";
```

So, in truth: I need to be able to insert via regex something like.

```
var regex = /^(yes_)(maybe_)(\w*)?/
```

I'm actually at a loss on how to do this.

So, if "maybe_" exists, I'll put "no" after it, else "no" goes after "yes_".

Comment: If you use conditions, good practice to do it in 2 steps: if .. else. Regex is pretty expensive in your case. Its seems good to do it with 1 row but ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
var newValue = someValue.replace(/yes_(maybe_)?/, "$&no_");

// "yes_maybe_next_year" --> "yes_maybe_no_next_year"
// "yes_sometime_later"  --> "yes_no_sometime_later"
```

Comment: yeah, after goofing around, I came up with this: .replace(/^(yes_)(maybe_)?/, "$1$2no_") ---> what does your $& do?

Comment: @VisionN - so in this case it would be short for my "$1$2"?